# extract sentences starting with keywords/phrases from rss feeds in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, rss, extract

I'm looking for a way to extract specific text from RSS feeds, specifically news sites.  I want to scrape the feed(s), looking for any example of [phrase], returning each match of that phrase and the rest of the sentence after it (just up to the full stop, nothing too nlp).

Closest thing I've found is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import feedparser
import re
import requests

def search_article(url, phrases):
    """
    Yield all of the specified phrases that occur in the HTML body of the URL.
    """
    response = requests.get(url)
    text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {"itemprop":"articleBody"})

    for phrase in phrases:
        for i in text:
            i = i.text
            block = ''
            block = block + i

            if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(phrase) + r'\b', block):
                yield phrase

def search_rss(rss_entries, phrases):
    """
    Search articles listed in the RSS entries for phases, yielding
    (url, article_title, phrase) tuples.
    """
    for entry in rss_entries:
        for hit_phrase in search_article(entry['link'], phrases):
            yield entry['link'], entry['title'], hit_phrase

def main(rss_url, phrases, output_csv_path, rss_limit=None):
    rss_entries = feedparser.parse(rss_url).entries[:rss_limit]
    with open(output_csv_path, 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for url, title, phrase in search_rss(rss_entries, phrases):
            print('"{0}" found in "{1}"'.format(phrase, title))
            w.writerow([url, phrase])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rss_url = 'http://www.theguardian.com/rss'
    phrases = ['in the future', 'the future will be',]
    main(rss_url, phrases, 'output.csv')
```

Which returns a list of the articles containing the phrase, but not the sentence context from within those articles that I'm looking for (I don't need the links or any other data, just the sentences containing those phrases).

I'm a beginner with python (but eager to learn, hence trying this!), some experience with regex.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Give an example, Put your current code, tell what have you tried until now?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your intention from "sentence", I assume that it starts after `.;<>` and ends before the same characters (`<` and `>` remove HTML elements from the selection). So you can do this in `for phrase in phrases:` block:

```
rxs = re.search(r'\b[^.;<>]*' + re.escape(phrase) + r'\b[^.;<>]*', block)
if rxs:
    yield rxs.extract_first()
```

What if my assumption is wrong? Well, you can change the regular expression pattern until it matches your purpose.

Comment: This looks really good, thank you!  I can definitely grapple with the regex myself, but would you mind putting your code in the context of the 'for phrase in phrases' block?  When I say sentences, I mean basically any words that occur after the (phrase), up to the next full stop.  So the ideal results would be something like '(phrase) is the best thing for the job.'

Comment: I don't know what is the block under `for i in text:` do. It seems it has a logical problem.

Comment: Hmm, well the script I posted does what it's meant to do (it just unfortunately doesn't do what I need it to do....)